# how to read environment variables in next js (in azure app service)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, azure-web-app-service

We are deploying the same image to different environments (dev, qa, prod)

We are hosting out nextjs application in azure app service and planning to read azure app settings as configuration

Could not find any help reading azure app settings from nextjs app

Comment: all app settings configurations will be available in runtime as environment variables, visible to the application. So you just need to access it through `process.env.NAME_OF_YOUR_SETTINGS`

Comment: @praveen-kumar Did you find a solution? because I have the same problem atm.

Answer (score 1):

You can read azure app settings from nextjs app by following below steps:

First, navigate to the app service in your Azure portal where the app is hosted. Search for Application Settings and add a new setting value.

I created one called PORT.

[image]

Now,In your application that you are deploying to the app service, read the value as shown:

```html
var port = process.env.PORT;
```

Comment: did you create your App Service in Azure as Container(Linux) or just Linux? I created mine as Container (Linux), i tried your solution with no success. :(